# Insert form values mixed with database table values into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with two tables, point and men.
The works are publication and edition. One publication can have multiple editions.
Point has three columns:
pub (eg, a, t, e) and edn 9ce, se, ne).
Now a-ce=2 point, a-se=1 point, t-ce=3 point, t-se=4 points etc.
These values are inserted into the points table and this is done.
The next table men is where executives write their works for the day.
This has four columns: name, pub, edn and point.
e.g. person 1 has entered a-ce and 2 point should be inserted into his name.
How do I use PHP for automatically calculate the pub and edn from point table and insert the corresponding value in men table?
The following code describes the insertion of works:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO men (name, pub, edn) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pub'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['edn'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_mathcon, $mathcon);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $mathcon) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Can you please reformulate? I do not understand what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: It will help you to read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Before you perform `INSERT query` on database2 you should perform a `SELECT query` on database1 for the appropriate `point`, based on the values of `$_POST['pub']` and `$_POST['edn']`.

Something like:

```
"SELECT point FROM point WHERE pub = $_POST['pub'] AND edn = $_POST['edn']"
```

then add the returned value to your `$insertSQL` string.

Another way to make this work is to query database1 at the start of the code, put the returned values in an Array and just read the value from the array using the entries entered by the editors.

Comment: thank you so much! this might be very obvious but to me it was great help. thanks again.